# How do I enable a Calculate button in visual basic when i need 2 radio buttons selected and text in a text box

Tags: vb.net

Alright so I'm writing a program that converts Celsius Kelvin and Fahrenheit. By default I have my calculate button disabled until the user puts in a temperature and selects the radio button for the corresponding temperature and what temperature is being converted to.  I am having a great deal of issues trying to enable the calculate button.  I'm not sure what to do since nested if statements in the calculate area are not working.  Here is what I have so far:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Public Class FmMain
    'Yes I understand that this program is very easy to break

    Private Sub BtnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnCalc.Click

        Try

            Dim num1 As Decimal
            Dim num2 As Decimal
            Dim Answer As Decimal
            Dim Flag As Integer
            Dim Flag2 As Integer
            Dim T1 As String

            'This is where I'm trying to enable the calculate button
            If TxtNum1.Text <> "" Then
                If RadC1.Checked Or RadF1.Checked Or RadK1.Checked Then
                    If RadC2.Checked Or RadF2.Checked Or RadK2.Checked Then
                        BtnCalc.Enabled = True
                        BtnCalc.Focus()
                    End If
                End If
            End If


            'This block of code makes sure that the input that is entered is numerical and does not break the program.
            If TxtNum1.Text <> "" Then 'I won't need this line once I can get the calculate button enabled and disabled at will
                If IsNumeric(TxtNum1.Text) Then

                    If RadF1.Checked And RadC2.Checked Then
                        Flag = 1
                    ElseIf RadF1.Checked And RadK2.Checked Then
                        Flag = 2
                    ElseIf RadC1.Checked And RadF2.Checked Then
                        Flag = 3
                    ElseIf RadC1.Checked And RadK2.Checked Then
                        Flag = 4
                    ElseIf RadK1.Checked And RadF2.Checked Then
                        Flag = 5
                    Else
                        Flag = 6
                    End If

                    If RadF2.Checked Then
                        Flag2 = 1
                    ElseIf RadC2.Checked Then
                        Flag2 = 2
                    Else
                        Flag2 = 3
                    End If

                    Answer = ModCalc.Temperature(num1, Flag, num2)
                    T1 = ModCalc.Temp(Flag2)
                    MessageBox.Show("The Answer is: " & Answer.ToString & " " & T1 & ".", "This is a Message Box", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number", "Bad Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                End If

            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number", "Bad Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End If


        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub
    'This just ensures that the user can't click the same radio button on both sides
    Private Sub RadF1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadF1.CheckedChanged
        If RadF1.Checked Then
            RadF2.Checked = False
            RadF2.Enabled = False
            RadC2.Enabled = True
            RadK2.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadC1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadC1.CheckedChanged
        If RadC1.Checked Then
            RadC2.Checked = False
            RadC2.Enabled = False
            RadF2.Enabled = True
            RadK2.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadK1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadK1.CheckedChanged
        If RadK1.Checked Then
            RadK2.Checked = False
            RadK2.Enabled = False
            RadF2.Enabled = True
            RadC2.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You're trying to enable the button in the button's onclick event handler.  That doesn't make any sense.  You should move the logic to enable the button to the radio button check changed events, and only enable the button if the proper ones are checked.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
BtnCalc.Enabled = TxtNum1.TextLength > 0 AndAlso
                  (RadC1.Checked OrElse RadF1.Checked OrElse RadK1.Checked) AndAlso
                  (RadC2.Checked OrElse RadF2.Checked OrElse RadK2.Checked)
```

That said, how can you be enabling the `BtnCalc` in its own `Click` event handler?  You need to do it when the state of the other controls changes.  The `Click` event can't be raised if the `Button` isn't enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. as other members have said - the code for enabling the button is inside the button's click event. If the button is disabled, the event will never fire and your code for checking the inputs wont get executed.

What I would suggest is to add a text changed handler for both text boxes which checks that both of them contain numric data and then enable the button like this :-

```
Private Sub TxtNum1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TxtNum1.TextChanged, TxtNum2.TextChanged
        If ((IsNumeric(TNum1.Text) = True) AndAlso (IsNumeric(TxtNum2.Text) = True)) Then
            btnCalc.Enabled = True
        End If
End Sub
```

However I wouldnt include the btnCalc.Focus command, because as soon as both text boxes have any valid numerical data in them, the focus will be transferred to the button and if you want to add more digits, you need to click back on the text boxes each time you press a key. Be it another number or even deleting a number

Adding the isnumeric functions into this section of code means that you can remove it from the code that checks which radio buttons are selected. Its always good to validate your inputs as soon as possible to avoid possible problems later in your code. It makes code much easier to debug if an error somewhere can be found in code close by.

Also, in the form designer, make sure that one radio button from each group is already checked by setting the Checked property to True. That would eliminate the need for checking to see if the radio buttons are checked.

OK on to the code that sets flags according to radio buttons. If you come back to your code in six months, you're not going to remember what setting Flag to 1 or to 2 means, so I would suggest you write bit of code at the top of the class definition using Enum to make this clear later on.. for example :-

just below the line ..    Public Class FmMain, add

```
Enum conversion
FtoC = 1
    FtoK = 2
    CtoF = 3
    CtoK = 4
    KtoF = 5
    KtoC = 6
End Enum
```

Then.. In your if statements, instead of setting Flag=1 you can type

```
Flag=conversion.FtoC
```

This makes things much more readable and maintainable later.

Finally you could do the same sort of thing for Flag as well, although not knowing exactly what the ModCalc code does, there may be better ways of doing things.

Hope this helps.